# How do I get a Mad Catz mouse to work?

Tags: drivers, 15.04, mouse

using a Mad Catz mouse - no other questions seem to help so I've decided to Ask Ubuntu.

I'm using a Mad Catz mouse, worked fine on Windows 10, deleted windows and went to ubuntu, now, I can move it but not interact on Close or Minimise buttons or anything else for that matter, I'm currently using a wireless mouse which is working fine - also my track pad is fine.

Please explain your answers simply as I'm a Linux Noob.

Thank-you!

Comment: Can your run `sudo dmesg` in a terminal right after boot and show us the output? It should spit out information about USB devices, and it's likely there's one about your mouse.

Comment: I just got a Mad Catz S3 PRO. Everything works fine out of the box on Linux. On a whim, I wondered what would happen if I programed everything with Windows and then plugged it back in to my Linux Box WhooHoo!! All the programming stuck!! Lights and button functions are just what I told them to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify `xorg.conf`. Append the following section to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf` (in a terminal, enter `pkexec gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf`):

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Mouse Remap"
        MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.7 Mouse"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

This eliminates the need to restart X and makes the mouse completely usable every time Ubuntu starts. Just modify `xorg.conf` with the section above and the R.A.T. 7 functions perfectly. Say goodbye to restarting X.

**Update:** The R.A.T. series of mice are now sold under the Mad Catz label, not Cyborg. Because of this, the Mad Catz product string might need modification to make the RAT work in Ubuntu. This means changing the Cyborg portion of the identification string (used to identify the USB device) to the string the Mad Catz RAT sends to the computer in order for X to recognize the RAT without freezing the buttons. Instead of using the string

```
MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.7 Mouse"
```

the Mad Catz might use something else (not tested). Product strings much match to avoid the button freeze issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, my RAT3 works now perfectly  (including dpi switch),  by the way, i use conf provided from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mad_Catz_Mouse

Comment: Run 'xinput list' in the terminal to the get the correct name to put for  MatchProduct

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to r.bitter for pointing out the directories!

Edited June 15th 2021

Step 1: find out all the mouse info that Linux reads from the device lsusb, in my case;

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0738:1713 Mad Catz, Inc.
Note that you will need the indo on ID

then use dmesg;

hid-generic 0003:0738:1713.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Mad Catz Mad Catz M.M.O.7 Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0

so I have [Mad Catz Mad Catz M.M.O.7 Mouse]

ok, so far so good, now, on the terminal type ; xinput list

Then find anything that relates to Rat 7 m.m.o in my case was ↳ Mad Catz Mad Catz M.M.O.7 Mouse id=11 [slave pointer (2)]

so......

In my case I have a Rat 7 m.m.o, so what I did was cd /etc/X11 then created xorg.conf and inside the file I pasted this:

```
    Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Mouse Remap"
    MatchProduct "Mad Catz Mad Catz M.M.O.7 Mouse|M.M.O.7"
    MatchIsPointer "true"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option    "Buttons" "24"
    Option    "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 10 11 12 0 0 0 16 17 7 6 0 0 0 0 0"
    Option    "AutoReleaseButtons" "20 21 22 23 24" 
    Option    "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection
```

close the file and save it.

then cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d create a file named: 50-vmmouse.conf then paste this:

```
    Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "evdev"
    Option         "Name" "Mad Catz Mad Catz M.M.O.7 Mouse|M.M.O.7"
    Option         "Vendor" "0738"
    Option         "Product" "1713"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "Buttons" "7"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
    Option         "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
    Option         "Resolution" "3200"
EndSection
```

Last but not least... still inside /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d create a file named 910-rat.conf

inside you are going top paste this:

```
Section "InputClass" 
Identifier "Mouse Remap 7" 
MatchProduct "Mad Catz Mad Catz M.M.O.7 Mouse|M.M.O.7" 
MatchIsPointer "true" 
MatchUSBID "0738:1713" 
Driver "evdev" 
Option "Buttons" "24" 
Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 0 21 22 23 24" 
Option "AutoReleaseButtons" "20" 
Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7" 

EndSection
```

REMEMBER to replace YOUR info instead of mine

Comment: Works with Kubuntu 19.04 as well. Only difference: the `xorg.conf.d` folder location is `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`.